# define is not defined Javascript Node

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, requirejs, require

I am trying to run a Javascript file with Node to post blog updates to Tumblr.

So far in my main.js file I have this:

```
// Tumblr Information
var tumblr = require('./vendor/tumblr');
tumblr.request(require('request'));
var Blog;

var jq = require('./vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min');
var reqq = require('./vendor/require');
var inher = require('./vendor/inheritance');

var grammars = require('./tracery/grammar');
```

But then I receive the following error when I run node main.js

```
ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\Documents\Google Drive\Programming\CMPM 147 Tracery\Tumblr Tracery\js\
tracery\grammar.js:6:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (B:\Documents\Google Drive\Programming\CMPM 147 Tracery\Tumblr Tracery\js\
main.js:11:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

And here is where the error is being thrown in the grammar.js file:

```
define(["./modifiers", "./node"], function(universalModifiers, Node) {'use strict';

    // other stuff...
});
```

I do not think a module is being loaded properly because it is stating the define function isn't defined. I believe this function comes from requireJS but I don't think I am loading it properly. Does anyone have any suggestions on why define might not be defined, or suggestions on how to load the correct module?

Thank you.

Comment: The tumblr part of the code isn't throwing the complaint. I got the tumblr part working find but the line that is causing the issue is the:

var grammars = require('./tracery/grammar')

Comment: Ah, I see -- the tumblr part of the path led me that way.

Comment: Why are you using `define`? That's not how you define a module in Node.js

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to load a library that is coded according to the AMD (Asynchronous Module Definition) pattern, which Node does not support natively. It is perfectly possible for the author of a library to write such library so that it can be loaded in Node. The users of the library have to *extend Node's module loading capabilities to understand AMD* in order to load such library.

There are multiple loaders you can use, the one I use is [amd-loader](https://github.com/ajaxorg/node-amd-loader). Once installed with `npm`, you just add

```
require("amd-loader");
```

before you load any AMD module.

Comment: Excellent, that fixed the problem! I didn't realize the library was written in the AMD pattern. I am still very new to Node and Javascript for that matter. Thanks again for your help!