# error ReferenceError: define is not defined after changing selectlist's default language using select2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I'm implementing asp.net core 3.1 and I've added select2 plugin to give the ability of searching in some of my selectlists and it works correctly. now my problem is how can I change its default language into persian language. I've written like the following in order to make my selectlist language into persian, however in the console there is an error like the following:
ReferenceError: define is not defined
 https://localhost:5001/language/fa.js:3

Here is my fa.js content:

```
define(function () {
  // Farsi (Persian)
  return {
    errorLoading: function () {
      return 'امکان بارگذاری نتایج وجود ندارد.';
    },
    inputTooLong: function (args) {
      var overChars = args.input.length - args.maximum;

      var message = 'لطفاً ' + overChars + ' کاراکتر را حذف نمایید';

      return message;
    },
    inputTooShort: function (args) {
      var remainingChars = args.minimum - args.input.length;

      var message = 'لطفاً تعداد ' + remainingChars + ' کاراکتر یا بیشتر وارد نمایید';

      return message;
    },
    loadingMore: function () {
      return 'در حال بارگذاری نتایج بیشتر...';
    },
    maximumSelected: function (args) {
      var message = 'شما تنها می‌توانید ' + args.maximum + ' آیتم را انتخاب نمایید';

      return message;
    },
    noResults: function () {
      return 'هیچ نتیجه‌ای یافت نشد';
    },
    searching: function () {
      return 'در حال جستجو...';
    },
    removeAllItems: function () {
      return 'همه موارد را حذف کنید';
    }
  };
});
```

And here below is what i have tried in my view:

```
<head>
    <link href="~/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>


<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="~/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="~/js/select2.min.js" src="~/language/fa.js"></script>

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        $(".statesSelect").select2({
            language: "fa"
        });

    });
</script>
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="mttable.Itemid" class="control-label mylabel">Item name</label>
                <select name="states" class="form-control statesSelect" asp-items="ViewBag.Itemid"></select>
            </div>
```

Comment: I don't know the answer but you can look at this https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2946

Comment: Please check the following threads: [Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817636/uncaught-referenceerror-define-is-not-defined-typescript) and [Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28450263/define-is-not-defined-javascript-node). Perhaps you need to include RequireJS before the fa.js reference.